# Ignoring Exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I try to understand below code, We will be using WebDriverWait  for waiting for an element in webpage, to avoid NoSuchElementException, but again why are we using ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class) in below code?

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(dr,20);
wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

What is the purpose of having ignoring here for which we already have wait? when to use ignoring(exception)?
Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when we are waiting for an element in the page, we dont use ignoring. Instead, we use "until". That adds a condition to the code. It doesnt throw any exceptions(or errors) until this condition is met or the time you give expires.

For example:
JavaScript:

```
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.xpath('/html/body/header/div')),20000)
```

Java:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div")))
```

These 2 codes are doing the same thing in Javascript and Java. Here we tell the selenium driver to wait for 20 seconds if the element in the page is not found(our condition) and then throw the error, if the element is found (condition is met)anytime before the given time, it will not wait and move on to the next code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It will ignore when after given time the element did not appear, and your test will not break, but if element was not found then ignoring might not be appropiate
, everything depends on what you need to do, if that elemen's visibility is optional then ignoring is ok, but if visibility is mandatory for your test, do not use ignoring